# Relative Distinguished Names and attributes for certificate request

Tags: openssl, request, certificate

in one project i have made certificate request creation with help of openssl functions. The procedure of request creation includes next steps:

- constructing "subject distinguished name" with openssl function "X509_NAME_add_entry_by_txt";
- adding "attributes" with "X509_REQ_add1_attr_by_txt";
- adding "extenstion attributes" with "X509V3_EXT_conf";

The problem is that i do not know exactly what "Relative Distinguished Names" and "attributes" values are possible and what are supported by openssl. Is there any full list of possible values of them? Is there any information about which of them supported by openssl?